# actionperformed not sensing button click

Tags: java, swing, action, jbutton, actionlistener

So I have some button:
`static JButton rpsls = new JButton(new ImageIcon(rpslsscaled));`
where rpslsscaled is some image. So I try to get the button

```
public class SomeClass implements ActionListener{
    ...
    static JButton rpsls = new JButton(new ImageIcon(rpslsscaled));
    ...
    class SomeInnerClass implements ActionListener{
    ...
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (e.getSource() == rpsls) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You clicked rpsls!");
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    ...
    }
}
```

When I press the button `rpsls`, nothing happens. It doesn't print "You clicked rpsls!".
Is this because of the 2 `actionPerformed` methods?

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

- Where do you add your ActionListener to your JButton?
- Why are you using static variables? There is no need, and in fact there is a strong argument *not* to do this.

---

Solution:

- Add your ActionListener to your JButton if you want the button to respond by calling `addActionListener(...)` on the JButton instance.
- Get rid of all unnecessary static modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You missed set the button with the listener:

```
SomeInnerClass instance = new SomeInnerClass();
rpsls.adddActionListener(instance);//Using the inner class
```

or

```
rpsls.adddActionListener(this);//for the main Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not have added an ActionListener on the button of the outer class.
Do this:

```
rpsls.adddActionListener(new SomeInnerClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

set an actionperformed on your button this will inturn capture the Event e when you click and the u can define your actionPerfomed as any other method or the as the inner you have up their

Comment: Regarding `"excuse me? "SORRY WASN'T PAYING ATTENTION WHILE DOING THIS, NO MORE ANSWERS PLEASE! Thanks! :) *Thanks for helping, though!*" Did you read that?"`: @Minecrafterguy64: are you trying on purpose to piss people off who are only trying to help you? If so, you are doing a wonderful job of it.